# Divs not going 100% height even with parent elements at height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have two divs set to display:table-cell; so they sit side by side and a row div for the display:table-row; and finally a #main div with display:table;. All the parent elements have height 100% but the #main div wont go. Ive tried everything I can think of to fix it and hoping its something simple I have missed. Below is my code.

**Styles**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

header {
    background: #1A446C;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2% 0 0 2%;
}
header h1 {
    color: #D4E6F4;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#main {
    background: #FDE8A5;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*padding-bottom: 50px;*/
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
nav {
    background: #8D0D19;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 16%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
nav ul li {
    color: #FFF;
}

#page {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 76%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
}
#page ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
}
#page h2, #page p {
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

footer {
    background: #1A446C;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="row">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div id="page">
                    <h2>Manage Content</h2>

                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Copyright 2015, </p>
        </footer>
    </div><!-- This Close Container -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#main {
        background: #FDE8A5;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        /*padding-bottom: 50px;*/
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

`vh` instead of `%` changes to View port Height
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5nbnr8Lk/1/)

There are a couple of relatively new CSS3 measurement units called:

[Viewport-Percentage (or Viewport-Relative) Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

What are Viewport-Percentage Lengths?

From the linked W3 Candidate Recommendation above:

The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
These units are vh (viewport height), vw (viewport width), vmin (viewport minimum length) and vmax (viewport maximum length).

How can this be used to make a divider fill the height of the browser?

For this question, we can make use of vh: 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport's height. That is to say, 100vh is equal to the height of the browser window, regardless of where the element is situated in the DOM tree:

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow didn't know those existed, thanks alot for the reference.